# jqGrid: Frozen columns of parent grid not working after adding subgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a subgrid. I made a few columns in the parent grid and subgrid as frozen. Frozen columns on subgrid works fine, but it does not work on the parent grid.

When I disable the subgrid by setting subGrid as false, frozen rows works perfectly on the parent.

Is there anything that I am missing which stops the frozen columns on the parent grid from working?

Here is my jqgrid:

```
$(function () {
"use strict";
var myData = {
        id: "509403957ae7d3929edcb812",
        name: "MYBOOK",
        chapters: [
            {
                name: "myfirstchapter",
                sequence: 10,
                title: "My First Chapter",
                filetype: "tex", 
                col3: "a", 
                col4: "b",
                files: [
                    { filetype: "tex", name: "myfile1", col3: "a", col4: "b" },
                    { filetype: "doc", name: "myfile2", col3: "c", col4: "d" },
                    { filetype: "doc", name: "myfile3", col3: "e", col4: "f" },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "mysecondchapter",
                sequence: 20,
                title: "My Second Chapter",
                filetype: "tex", 
                col3: "a", 
                col4: "b",
                files: [
                    { filetype: "tex", name: "myfirstfile", col3: "a", col4: "b" },
                    { filetype: "tmpl", name: "myfileb", col3: "c", col4: "d" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    $grid = $("#list");

$grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: myData.chapters,
    colNames: ["Sequence", "Name", "Title", "Filetype", "col3", "col4"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "sequence", width: 65, key: true, frozen: true },
        {name: "name", width: 200, frozen: true },
        {name: "title", width: 150},
        {name: "filetype", width: 130},
        {name: "col3", width: 130},
        {name: "col4", width: 130}
    ],
    rowNum: 3,
    rowList: [3, 5, 10],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "sequence",
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    autowidth: false,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    width: 600,
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridId + "_t'></table>");
        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + subgridId);
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).files,
            colNames: ["Name", "Filetype", "col3", "col4"],
            colModel: [
                {name: "name", width: 130, key: true, frozen: true},
                {name: "filetype", width: 130, frozen: true},
                {name: "col3", width: 130},
                {name: "col4", width: 130}
            ],
            height: "100%",
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: "name",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_"
        }).jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
    }
});
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
$grid.jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Guriddo jqGrid subgrid can not be used when frozen columns are on.

[Here you can read](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/frozencols/#notes-limitations) all the limitation of Guriddo jqGrid.
We do not know how this is in free-jqgrid.

Comment: Thanks. I thought jqGrid and free-jqgrid were the same. Is there any work-around available to  overcome the limitation?